# How can I specify the install directory with TinyTake?

Tags: windows-7, screen-recorder

How can I specify the install directory with TinyTake?

The installer say I can click on `options` but I don't see any:

[image]

I use TinyTake on Microsoft Windows 7.

Comment: if you click install, it will ask you the install directory, just tried. Windows 10 TinyTake v.5.2.11

Comment: @CaldeiraG thanks, I guess the option was added in TinyTake v5

Comment: Definitely, v4.3.5.0 doesn't have the option to choose, tried as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the version you're trying to install (v.4.3.5.0) there is no option to select the installation directory, it just installs.

On the latest version as of Nov 2019 (v.5.2.11) if you click Install, it will ask you to choose the installation directory.